# OPENSSL Error outputting keys and certificates 94640000:error:0308010C

Tags: cmd, openssl

I'm trying to my dummy pfx file convert to crt and key file with openssl cmd command. But after log in key and press enter, I always getting this error. How can ı fix? Someone can help? Thx.

Error outputting keys and certificates
94640000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto\evp\evp_fetch.c:373:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()

Comment: This is not programming or development and [your image makes my eyes bleed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) but you are apparently using **OpenSSL 3.0.x** which no longer supports 'legacy' algorithms like the deliberately weak RC2-40 traditionally used for PKCS12 certbags unless you **specify `-legacy`, and** probably the **ShiningLight** Windows build which in at least some versions doesn't support `-legacy` or needs an envvar set to make it work, **see** https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Main/issues/3335

Comment: Sorry for this :( Thank you for your answer. I will review it as soon as possible.  Have a good day ^^

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the solution! You might consider converting your comment to an answer so more people find it